# Is it fine to post an answer that elaborates an edge case of another answer?

Tags: discussion

Here is the link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/142800/74040

The author of the answer based his answer on an edge case that happened while application of the accepted answer.

What is this site's take on this situation? Is it fine to post this as an answer; or should it instead have been purposed as an edit to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the answer goes into detail regarding an edge case brought up in another answer, I do not see any problem.

From what you have established, the new answer goes into more detail on a particular issue that was only *mentioned* in the original. Perhaps the original poster thought it was not worth going into detail, for the minority of the cases that would need to take the extra considerations, or progress with the more particular answer. Regardless, it is useful to have a detailed answer regarding these situations, for users that *do* find themselves in this minority.

If the additions are *semantical*, I would favour downvoting. If not, take your own judgement into consideration, in regards to voting.

As a whole, there is no real problem, here.